# Databricks-connect test : TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Tags: azure, databricks

I'm setting up the databricks setup from local machine while after all configuration I receive following error with
`databricks-connect test`

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"**main**", mod_spec)
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\databricks-connect.exe__main__.py", line 9, in 
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\databricks_connect.py", line 262, in main
test()
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\databricks_connect.py", line 186, in test
spark_home = os.path.dirname(pyspark.**file**)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the configuration, which can be easily done via

```
databricks-connect configure
```

You will need the following parameters:

**URL**: A URL of the form https://.cloud.databricks.com. 
**User token**: A user token. 
**Cluster ID**: The ID of the cluster you created. You can obtain the cluster ID from the URL. Here the cluster ID is 0304-201045-xxxxxxxx.

For more info, please see https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-connect.html

Answer (score 0):

Check your Spark_Home , If SPARK_HOME is set to a version of Spark other than the one in the client, you should unset the SPARK_HOME variable and try again.

Check your IDE environment variable settings, your .bashrc, .zshrc, or .bash_profile file, and anywhere else environment variables might be set. You will most likely have to quit and restart your IDE to purge the old state, and you may even need to create a new project if the problem persists.

You should not need to set SPARK_HOME to a new value; unsetting it should be sufficient